# Socket receive buffer size

Tags: c#, sockets, c#-3.0

Is there a way to determine the receive buffer size of a TCPIP socket in c#. I am sending a message to a server and expecting a response where I am not sure of the receive buffer size.

```
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.125.125.226"),20060);
            Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                              SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            server.Connect(ipep);

            String OutStr= "49|50|48|48|224|48|129|1|0|0|128|0|0|0|0|0|4|0|0|32|49|50";

            byte[] temp = OutStr.Split('|').Select(s => byte.Parse(s)).ToArray(); 

            int byteCount = server.Send(temp);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[255];
            int res=0;
            res = server.Receive(bytes);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 6):

The size of the buffer used to receive data is application or protocol dependent. There's no way within the language to tell what the size of your receive buffer ought to be. Nor is there any socket function that can be used that says 'you need a 23867 bytes to receive this message'. In general your application has to work out from the protocol what size the receive buffer should be and how to handle this. Typically a protocol will either:

- specify the number of bytes in the message.
- specify a terminating character (for example hdlc using 0x7e to indicate the end of the message)

A consequence of this is that your application might need to deal with split messages. For example the server might send a message that is 2000 bytes but your receive buffer is only 1000 bytes, you'll have to write some code to maintain the state telling you if you've completed a message or are partially complete.

Comment: Since there is no terminating character is there any way such as to loop until the receiving bytes are over.

Comment: @Kanishka one normally uses a multiple of the systems page size for best performance.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724958(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Kanishka: Yeah have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx. It outlines how to use Socket.Receive to determine if there's more data waiting to be processed in the `Remarks` section.

Answer (score 4):

TCP is a stream of bytes. It knows nothing of your concept of messages.

As such it's up to you to provide the necessary message framing information within that stream of bytes. Common ways to do this include prefixing the message with a header which contains the total length of the message or terminating the message with a character that cannot otherwise appear in a valid message.

I speak about TCP message framing here: http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/10/message-framing-a-length-prefixed-packet-echo-server.html though it's in reference to C++ code so it might not be any use to you.

It's usually slightly more performant for a message consumer to deal with length prefixed messages and it's often slighly more performant for a message producer to produce character delimited messages. Personally I prefer length prefixed messages wherever possible.

With a length prefixed message you would first send x bytes of data which are the length of the message, the peer would then know that it always has to read at least x bytes to work out the length and from that point it knows the size of the resulting message and can read until it has that many bytes.

With character delimited messages you simply keep reading and scanning all of the data that you have read until you find the message delimiter. You have then got a whole message, and possibly more data (part of the next message?) in the buffer to process after that.